# IMPORTANT QUESTION... PLEASE DO NOT AVOID AND READ PROPERLY BEFORE ANSWERING :)

Tags: halal-haram, music, halal-certification

Assalamulaikum. I wanted to know about music. I want to do a youtube channel on a racing game (asphalt 8). I want to use some non-lyrical music as intro. The game's races are full of engine sounds and some sound (not lyrical music. Its a 1 sec sound. I don't if its considered as music) So, now i need to know if the non-lyrical 15-20sec music is halal or haram. I also need to know if the engine sounds and sounds at starting and ending are haram or halal? If you want i can give a link of a video for example

Comment: Link of the example video (watching 3-5 minutes is enough to understand my question) :  https://youtu.be/DYZqtkJR470

Comment: Question titles should be related to the content. Everybody thinks his question is important. Writing in capital letters is mainly regarded as shouting (inappropriate behavior).

Comment: Thats 999+ intelligence level thing to have your question answered as quickly as possible xD..

Comment: @Medi1Saif, it can be unimportant or useless thing to you... But it is important to me.. Everybody has some entertainment things on their life and asphalt 8 is for me.. I had the dream of being a youtuber for a long time without braking any rules of religion.. Hope you understand the situation and give more respect to others question :)

Comment: @ahmed butt... Yeah, you are saying the truth.. I had asked a question months back but it didn't get answered :(

Comment: Instead of replaying to my comment you'd better act upon it before the question may get closed or deleted (due to down votes) . Also use relevant tags halal-certification has absolutely no relation here you'd better add game instead.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of music is a big topic among the muslim community some ulama says that there is no problem with music as long as it uses only the daff, others say music is haram, and some says that music and songs are halal, but as long as they contain lyrics or such that are porhipted by islam like swear words or the mention of sex and alchol.

Allah knows best

Hope that answers your question and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Car engine sound is not haram.....The music which you are referring to at the start  of the video is halal if no musical intrument is used except duff.
Personal advice:do not waste your time on this...
Hadith

It was narrated from Ibn 'Abbas (رضي الله عنه) that he said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

"Good health and free time [are] two blessings from Allah that many people do not make good use of."

Its isnad is saheeh, al-Bukhari (6412)]

Musnad Ahmad 2340
Arabic/English book : Book 25, Hadith 2340
Musnad Ahmed

Comment: Thanks for your advice. By the way, what were you referring as "duff"? If you watch the video, at the start of race and at the end of race, it has a sound. Is it considered as music?

Comment: Bro search duff on google..its an muscial instrument which is permissable in islam.at the start of the race i only heard the voice of sportcars not any music

Comment: The sound at the start and end of race is not from any musical instrument as per my view..plz do consult a person who know about religion and differentiating between musical instrument...P.S i am not an music speciallist so i am sure that is  musical intrument or not

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to me :)

Comment: But i don't know any music specialist  who will talk with a normal person like me :(

Comment: Btw what the name of ur channel?

Comment: Will subscribe :)

Comment: @ahmed... You play asphalt 8? :o

Comment: Btw.. The channel's name is aguila negra... I like this channel cause it doesn't use music but other channel use bad music :(